# Sign a call to Coinbase Pro API with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, base64, sha256, coinbase-api

I'm going mad trying to send my first API call to Coinbase Pro using Google Apps Script. In node.js is pretty easy (https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message) but doing the same with Google scripts is just returning again and again "Invalid Signature".

This is the code I'm using:

```js
function GetMyAccounts () {
  var globalvars_CB = {
   'apikey'     : 'f7d20a*******18c',
   'secret'     : '******pIIitRbWCv9N/mMWaR*****mGQMuI+m/vSbU1zuh5U6WFiFw==',
   'passphrase' : 'ceacdsewfcsa',
   'uri'        : 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com'
  }
  
  var requestPath = '/accounts';
  
  var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  var options = {
    'method' : 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,     
    'headers' : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'CB-ACCESS-KEY' : globalvars_CB.apikey,
      'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' : SignAPICall(globalvars_CB.secret, timestamp, 'GET', requestPath, ''),
      'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' : timestamp,
      'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE' :  globalvars_CB.passphrase,
          }
  }  
    
  var responseJson = UrlFetchApp.fetch(globalvars_CB.uri+requestPath, options);
  
  Logger.log(responseJson);
 }
    

function SignAPICall(secret, timestamp, method, requestPath, body) {

  var what = (timestamp + method + requestPath + body);
  
  var decodedsecret = Utilities.base64Decode(secret).toString();
  
  var hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(what, decodedsecret);
 
  hmac = Utilities.base64Encode(hmac);
  
  return (hmac);    

}
```

I really need help :-) - Thanks!

Comment: I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I cannot test the request to the API using above modified script. So can you test the request in you environment? If that was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replied. I thought I had answered... Your change didn't work and the reason is that the function "Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature" require two strings or two byte[] nut not a combination of it. I will post the right code that made this working well. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. My answer proposed `computeHmacSha256Signature(byte, byte)` because you are using `var decodedsecret = Utilities.base64Decode(secret)`. So I used `Utilities.newBlob(what).getBytes()`. In your additional answer, I think that `Utilities.base64Decode(Utilities.base64Encode(timestamp + method + requestPath + body))` is the same with `Utilities.newBlob(what).getBytes()`. So I couldn't understand about the difference between my answer and your answer. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2):

In your script, it supposes that your request headers except for the value of `CB-ACCESS-SIGN` and endpoint are correct. Please be careful this.

#### Modification point:

- In the case of `Utilities.base64Decode(secret).toString()`, the array is converted to the string. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.

When above point is reflected, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, the function `SignAPICall` is modified.

```
function SignAPICall(secret, timestamp, method, requestPath, body) {
  var what = (timestamp + method + requestPath + body);
  var decodedsecret = Utilities.base64Decode(secret);  // Modified
  var res = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(Utilities.newBlob(what).getBytes(), decodedsecret);  // Modified
  hmac = Utilities.base64Encode(res);
  return hmac;
}
```

- In this case, `value` and `key` of `computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)` are the byte array.

#### Note:

- When I checked above modified script by comparing the sample scripts of [the official document](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message), I could confirm that the same result can be obtained.
- Unfortunately, I cannot test the request to the API using above modified script while I can confirm that the same signature from the sample script at the official document is retrieved from the above modified script. So please test the request in you environment. When you requested to the API using above modified script, when an error occurs, please check the request headers, endpoint and secret, again.

#### References:

- [Signing a Message](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message)
- [base64Decode(encoded)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded)
- [computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue,-key)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to it. It was a problem with the type of data I submitted to "Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature". In the code you can find the function working well.

```js
function SignAndCallAPI(method, requestPath, body) {

  var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
  
  var what = Utilities.base64Decode(Utilities.base64Encode(timestamp + method + requestPath + body));
  
  var decodedsecret = Utilities.base64Decode(globalvars_CB.secret);
  
  var hmac = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(what, decodedsecret));
     
  var options = {
    'method' : method,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,     
    'headers' : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'CB-ACCESS-KEY' : globalvars_CB.apikey,
      'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' : hmac,
      'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' : timestamp,
      'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE' :  globalvars_CB.passphrase,
     }
  }  
      
   var responseJson = UrlFetchApp.fetch(globalvars_CB.uri+requestPath, options);
  
  Logger.log(responseJson);
  return(responseJson);  

}
```