# POST requests with the Coinbase Pro API using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, coinbase-api

I'm working with the Coinbase Pro API and while it's working well for GET requests I'm getting an "Invalid signature" when I try a POST request to place an order. I suspect that this may be something related to the "body" of the message since this is the only difference with the GET where "body" is empty.

I'm wondering if someone can help me on this.

```js
function SellMarket (product,amount) {
  var requestPath = '/orders';
  var method = 'POST';
  var body = JSON.stringify({
    "type": "market",
    "side": "buy",
    "product_id": product,
    //"size": amount,
    'size': '1.0'
  });
  
  Logger.log('Sell - Body = '+body); 

  var responseJson = SignAndCallAPI(method, requestPath, body);
  Logger.log('Sell Executed = '+responseJson); 
}  


function SignAndCallAPI(method, requestPath, body) {

  var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
  var what = Utilities.base64Decode(Utilities.base64Encode(timestamp + method + requestPath + body));
  var decodedsecret = Utilities.base64Decode(globalvars_CB.secret);
  
  var hmac = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(what, decodedsecret));
     
  var options = {
    'method' : method,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,     
    'headers' : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'CB-ACCESS-KEY' : globalvars_CB.apikey,
      'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' : hmac,
      'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' : timestamp,
      'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE' :  globalvars_CB.passphrase,
     }
  }  
      
  var responseJson = UrlFetchApp.fetch(globalvars_CB.uri+requestPath, options);
  
  return(responseJson);  

}
```

Comment: If [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63575840/7108653), had been resolved, I think that the authorization script of your this script is correct. In this case, can you confirm whether each value of `body` is correct, again?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. Yes, I think that all the values in body are correct but still not working :-(

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @AlbertSampietro could you update the code to the working version.  I'm running into the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Untested suggestion, I recommend changing this bit in your code (in `SignAndCallAPI` function):

```
var options = {
  'method' : method,
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true,     
  'headers' : {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY' : globalvars_CB.apikey,
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' : hmac,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' : timestamp,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE' :  globalvars_CB.passphrase,
  }
}
```

to:

```
const options = {
  method: method,
  payload: body,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  muteHttpExceptions: true,     
  headers: {
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY': globalvars_CB.apikey,
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': hmac,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE':  globalvars_CB.passphrase,
  },
};
```

due to the reasons below:

1. Although you pass `body` to `SignAndCallAPI` function and use `body` in HMAC computation, you don't appear to actually include `body` in the POST request sent to the server. I was expecting to see it as the value to a `payload` property of your `options` object.
2. `UrlFetchApp` documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) seems to indicate that `Content-Type` should be specified in the `contentType` property of your `options` object (as opposed to explicitly including a `Content-Type` header).
3. I've not looked at the Coinbase API documentation in detail (https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#place-a-new-order), but `body` seems okay. You'll also want to make sure the HMAC computation for the `CB-ACCESS-SIGN` request header is as described in the documentation (https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! - I added the **payload: body,** as you suggested and this worked. Thanks!